# ios - Font issue while Printing HTML using AirPrint

Tags: objective-c, airprint, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I am printing HTML page using **air print**. Here is my Code

```
UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.jobName = @"Print";
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;

UIPrintInteractionController *printController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
printController.showsPageRange = NO;
printController.printInfo = printInfo;

UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter *formatter = [[UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithMarkupText:_PrintHTMLText];
printController.printFormatter = formatter;
```

Everything is printing fine. But only i get the problem of **changed font** and the printed text.

I tried printing same **HTML** through **Web** but it is printing right. But as i try from **device** the font changes by its own.

What i need to do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved when i added

```
formatter.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 20);
```